# How can I assign sequences to constants in the CONSTANTS section of a TLA+ configuration file?

Tags: configuration, constants, model-checking, tla+, tlc

I've tried

```
CONSTANTS seq = <<5,6,7>>
```

but TLC gives me a syntax error:

> Error: TLC found an error in the
>   configuration file at line 1. It was
>   expecting = or <- and didn't find it.

I've also tried to include the `Sequences` module in the configuration file, to no avail.

So... what do I have to do to assign a sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember ever facing this problem and my TLC is too rusty to try and give you a first hand answer (I just restarted using the TLA+ toolbox).

From the post linked bellow, however, I figure that you can't instantiate constants with sequences through the TLC config files.

http://bbpress.tlaplus.net/topic/creating-a-sequence-from-a-set

Even though the question is old, leaving an answer may help future TLAers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly assign to a constant in the TLA+ file. If you're using the toolbox, write `CONSTANTS seq`, then in the model add the tuple you want as an ordinary assignment.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that you need a separate `.tla` file for that. Suppose you have "Main.tla" as you source file. You want `MyConst` to have value `<<1,2,3>>`. TLA+ toolbox generates `MC.tla` where it puts the constants:

```
---- MODULE MC ----
EXTENDS Main, TLC

const_uniq12345 = <<1,2,3>>
====
```

in `MC.cfg`, there will be the line

```
CONSTANT MyConst <- const_uniq12345
```

Note that `MyConst = const_uniq12345` won't work -- if you use `=` instead of `<-`, `MyConst` will contain model value `const_uniq12345` instead of `<<1, 2, 3>>`

I used https://github.com/hwayne/tlacli to be able to run TLC from command line (TLA toolbox has awful UX), and I was able to supply a tuple constant with help of extra `.tla` file like this. I used meaningful name instead of `const_uniq12345` too, of course. Had to call `java -cp /path/to/tla2tools.jar ...` manually, though (got the full command using `--show-script` option of `tlacli`), because currently `tlacli` doesn't handle `<-` in the config.